# Video Streaming from raspberry zero to an external server

Tags: camera, pi-zero-w, streaming-video

I'm aware of streaming  live video using on the RaspberryPi itself as a server. But is there a way to send the video from the raspicam to an external web-streamer so that if I have multiple people viewing a stream it doesn't use up the resources of the pi? What protocol and server should i use? My raspberry is a raspberry pi zero w and i want to stream at the local network via wifi.
Thanks.

Comment: does the external web-streamer accept input streams?

Comment: Yes thats the point that it should accept the video stream from the raspberry. The plan is : Raspicam -> server(gateaway)->multiple clients(web browsers).

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of camera streamer tools/package and I have tested almost all of them then deduced the `motion` is the better one. It has a simple stream web page and the key advantage is the configuration file.

---

### Motion installation:

You can install it simply by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install motion
```

---

### Motion configuration:

Check [this link - (/etc/motion/motion.conf)](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html) out.

Comment: Ok I will give it a try.