# How do I stream video from raspberry pi cam to my android phone app in order to access it from anywhere?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, picamera

I'm a little bit new to the raspberry pi. Currently, I have a raspberry pi camera recording live video. I want to transfer this stream to an android app I developed. I really don't know where to start, and I would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: can you give some detail of the android app. Since you've completed that, your pi needs to send the stream in a way that is compatible with the app

Comment: Its an ionic app

Comment: 'ionic app" does not help

Comment: @Ajay If you got an answer, please post it as a new answer or "accept" one of the answers below if it did work.

Answer (score 2):

We have developed something that you want. You need to install the `motion` package on your raspberry pi. It will transmit streams over HTTP/HTTPS protocol with authentication.
You should install `motion` then configure it to access the web page over any hosts over LAN or the internet. Then, add these streams to a web-view on your android application.

---

1. **installation:**
   [Video Streaming from raspberry to an external server](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/108546/44221)
2. **Configuration:**
   [/etc/motion/motion.conf](https://motion-project.github.io/motion_config.html)
   You can configure stream quality according your bandwidth limitations.
3. **Make it more secure:**
   [Motion security](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107872/44221)
   If you are concerned about the security of the streams, you can make it much more secure with some configuration and insight.